# Access controller scope from directive of nested directive

Tags: angularjs

please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DavidSlavik/N7aKa/12/) and help me find a way to access function myAlert from nested directive "choice". A found some solutions where was shared some properties of scope like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zbD95/6/ but I need use functions and properties from scope together.

Thanks!!!

Here is duplicate of my fiddle:
HTML part of fiddle:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <choice-tree ng-model="myTree"></choice-tree>  
  <hr />
  <!--$scope.myTree = {{myTree | json}}-->
</body>
</html>
```

JS part of fiddle:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

function Choice(name, children) {
  this.name = name;
  this.checked = false;
  this.children = children || [];
}

var apparel = new Choice('Apparel', [
  new Choice('Mens Shirts', [
    new Choice('Mens Special Shirts'),
  ]),
  new Choice('Womens Shirts'),
  new Choice('Pants')
]);
var boats = new Choice('Boats');

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.myTree = [apparel, boats]; 

  $scope.myAlert = function(ev){
    alert('ad');
  };
});

app.directive('choiceTree', function() {
      return {
          template: '<ul><choice ng-repeat="choice in tree"></choice></ul>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          tree: '=ngModel'
        }
      };
});

app.directive('choice', function($compile) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
    //In the template, we do the thing with the span so you can click the 
    //text or the checkbox itself to toggle the check
    template: '<li>' +
      '<span ng-click="myAlert(choice)">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="choice.checked"> {{choice.name}} - {{name}}' +
      '</span>' +
    '</li>',
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

      //Add children by $compiling and doing a new choice directive
      if (scope.choice.children.length > 0) {
        var childChoice = $compile('<choice-tree ng-model="choice.children"></choice-tree>')(scope)
        elm.append(childChoice);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the '&' syntax to allow your isolated scope to call a method defined on the parent scope.  Also, you don't need any transclusion for these directives.

HTML:

```
<choice-tree ng-model="myTree" my-alert="myAlert()"></choice-tree>
```

Directives:

```
app.directive('choiceTree', function () {
    return {
        template: '<ul><choice ng-repeat="choice in tree"></choice></ul>',
        replace: true,
        //transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tree: '=ngModel',
            myAlert: '&'
        },
    };
});

app.directive('choice', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //transclude: true,
        template: '<li>' +
            '<span ng-click="myAlert()">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="choice.checked"> {{choice.name}} - {{name}}' +
            '</span>' +
            '</li>',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            //Add children by $compiling and doing a new choice directive
            if (scope.choice.children.length > 0) {
                var childChoice = $compile('<choice-tree ng-model="choice.children" my-alert="myAlert()"></choice-tree>')(scope)
                elm.append(childChoice);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/ButMc/).

Comment: It's what I need!!! Thank you!! Can you help me ones more, please? Existing way to send parameters from child "choice" item? Like this? <span ng-click="myAlert($event)"> I need work with item scope in myAlert function...

Comment: @David, I'm confused by your request... do you want the myAlert() function to received an $event object or some other data?

Comment: Yes I need object $event, usually when I send object $event from angular in ng-click function like a parameter. It's contains informations about actual thread of scope (using in ng-repeat). Do you understand me now Mark?

Comment: To pass the $event information to the MyAlert() function, add it to where it is called:  
  
    <span ng-click="myAlert($event)">  
  
and also add it to the function declaration:  
  
    $scope.myAlert = function($event){  
        alert('ad');  
        // You should have access to the $event object now  
    };  
  
Hope this helps!

Comment: @SteveJ, do you have a working fiddle? I tried this (just now, and also back in March) and it does not seem to work.  Besides, with the `&` syntax/binding, you need to use a special syntax when passing arguments (and I couldn't get that to work either).

Comment: @MarkRajcok, I apologize for not getting back to you sooner!  For some reason I only just today saw that I had a message in my inbox.  Must be my old eyes.  :-)  Here is a working fiddle for passing the $event object to an event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLJackson1/cEqW6/

I will post again when I have a fiddle of how to pass arguments to a function passed to a directive via the "scope" property.

Comment: @DavidSlavík, I hope my comment to Mark helps you, too, though it's probably too late now.  My apologies!

Comment: @DavidSlavík, we were trying to get the $event parameter to work inside a directive template (not a scope method as shown in your fiddle).

Comment: @MarkRajcok Ok, I updated my fiddle to include a click event in a directive.  It accesses the $event and forwards it to the passed-in function.  Let me know if you have any more questions: http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLJackson1/cEqW6/4/